# BigQuery and Grafana timeseries

Tags: google-bigquery, count, timestamp, grafana

Hello how are you? I consult you because I need to make a query to bigquery which is a count and bring the maximum number of values ​​grouped by date and pass it to a timeseries graph in grafana. My current query has the problem that it brings me an average of values ​​and I I want the values ​​that count distinct brings me, besides they are float. Perhaps there is a better way to perform a query and bring the maximum number of values ​​in a specific time. I leave what I have so far for you to see.
From already thank you very much; Cheers

In grafana:

with
users as(select timestamp(timestamp) as fecha, count(distinct u) as uin from `test_todaydata_view`
WHERE   ev like "%p%" and date(timestamp) = current_date('UTC-3')   group by fecha order by fecha asc),

filas as (SELECT  timestamp(fecha) + INTERVAL 7 MINUTE as ff, count(uin) OVER(ORDER BY uin asc  ROWS BETWEEN unbounded PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as usuarios FROM users  )

select datetime_trunc(ff,MINUTE) AS fem, AVG(usuarios) OVER(ORDER BY ff  RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as usuarios  from filas where $__timeFilter(ff) group by ff,usuarios

[dashboard in grafana](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWYNe.png)

Comment: Hello @Esteban Perez, I'm having a tough time to understand your problem from your text. Can you provide example data, e.g. a sample from the table you're querying and an expected result table?

Comment: thanks for answering. the current result with bigquery is this [resultado actual con bigquery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6eTwM.png) the most similar result to what is expected is this one, only that it should mark more users as in the first photo and also go from 00:00 to 23:00: [resultado esperado](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrCO7.png)